# Maximizing a function by minimizing its inverse

Tags: algorithm, function, optimization

Let's say I have a function f(x) defined over a given range [a,b] for which f(x) > 0. I want to maximize f, but my algorithm can only minimize a given function.

Given the premises, is there any difference in minimizing -f(x) or 1/f(x) ? 
To me, given that f(x) is always positive, there is no difference at all, as the global maximum becomes the global minimum of [a,b] in either cases.
Precision : I use a standard genetic algorithm for the process. My principal concern lies in how it explores the space depending on the function used, but so far, there seem to be no difference at all.

Comment: `1/f(x)` is a reciprocal, a function inverse is something entirely different.

Comment: I think any minimization algorithm uses gradients or some approximation thereof, and 1/f(x) has radically different gradients from those of f(x). In simple cases it probably doesn't matter, but when finite precision is involved, you better be careful.

Comment: @n.m.: genetic algorithms usually rely on function evaluations, not on gradients.

Comment: @timk: prefer -f, faster to compute and numerically neutral.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If however the function is required to be positive, take `g(x):=-(f(x))+a+1` where `a:=max{f(x):x in [a,b] }`, if it is known.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Inverse function is a mistranslation from my French. The genetic algorithm I use relies on function evaluation and not gradients, so I believe it does not matter. Running time between both cases is similar within a minute and the results are also similar. For this specific case, it does not seem to be a big issue, however thanks for the infos, I shall use -f in the future.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you could run into numerical issues. For example, if f(x) in range [a,b] takes up large values you could end up with rounding errors if you use 1/f(x) as opposed to -f(x). I would stick with minimizing -f(x).